# Page Breaks not working when a subreport is within another subreport

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with multiple subreports.  The page breaks work fine.  It works like this, with each number being a subreport, and within that there are different products.  Not every customer has all the products so I separate them by surrounding each service with a rectangle, put the page break location at Start and disable the page break via formula if they don't have the product:

1. HVAC

   - Yearly Service
   - Repair Insurance
2. Plumbing

   - Installations
   - Emergency Repair

It works perfectly.  We'll call that the Management Summary.  I need to put the Management Summary, along with other reports into a report package, so I've created a Master report with subreports for all of my reports, including the Management Summary.  Then the subreport pagination in the Management Summary stops working.   Emergency Repair starts in the middle of the page after Installations, when it normally starts on a new page.

Any idea why?  I'm using VS 2017 with the Reporting Services Project extension. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, page breaks that are defined within the subreports are not honoured by the parent report.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine the exact cause of the pagination issue without more information or seeing your report design. However, here are a few possible reasons that could cause this behavior:

1. Page break settings in the subreport may have changed: When you embed a subreport within another report, the page break settings in the subreport may not work as expected. Ensure that the page break settings in the subreport are correct and are not being overridden by the master report.
2. Different page sizes between the subreport and master report: If the subreport and master report have different page sizes, this could affect the pagination. Make sure that the page size and margins are consistent across all the reports.
3. Overlapping report items: If there are any overlapping report items, such as rectangles or tables, this could cause unexpected pagination behavior. Ensure that all report items are properly aligned and that there are no overlapping items.
4. Grouping and sorting: If the subreport is grouped or sorted, this could affect the pagination. Ensure that the grouping and sorting settings are consistent across all reports.
5. Report rendering format: Depending on the rendering format, the pagination behavior may differ. Ensure that the subreport and master report are rendered in the same format.

I would suggest reviewing the page break settings, page size, margins, grouping, sorting, and report item alignment for both the subreport and the master report to identify any inconsistencies that could be causing the pagination issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have checked all of those things.  But thank you for your attention and ideas.